# How can I use slice filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I filter content like 0-9 then 9-18 then 18-28 and so on.. in Django using a `slice` filter or any other option?, SO please suggest me.

```
<li class="mega-title"><span>column 01</span>
  <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
    {% for subcategory in category.children.all|slice:":9" %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'shop' shop='shop' pk=subcategory.pk %}">{{subcategory.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}                                                         
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="mega-title"><span>column 02</span>
  <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
    {% for subcategory in category.children.all|slice:"[09:9]" %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'shop' shop='shop' pk=subcategory.pk %}">{{subcategory.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}                                                       
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `slice` filter:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

```
{% for subcategory in category.children.all|slice:":9" %}
{% for subcategory in category.children.all|slice:"10:18" %}
....
```